# Applying assoc several times using a loop in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a quick way in Clojure, without the use of recur, to apply an assoc to an element several times in a row?

That is, something like:

```
(defn set-thing 
  [foo i val] 
  (assoc foo i val))

(let [foo [3 4 2 5 8]]
  (last (for [i (range 0 (count test))] 
    (set-thing foo i 32)))
```

The code above, however obviously does not do what I am after. The above function would simply return a vector where the last value is 32 and the rest remains unchanged. What I am after is to get a vector back where all values have been set to 32.

It is absolutely necessary for the set function to be used, as my code looks significantly different to that of the code above: thus preventing the use of map. The actual code is wrapped up pretty deep in structs upon structs.

Is it possible to achieve this effect, once again, without the use of recur?

**Edit:**

Here is a piece of code using loop and recur, doing what I wish to achieve.

```
(defn fill!
  "Fills the terminal with one specific tile."
  [{:keys [screen] :as term} tex-x tex-y color]
  (let [grid-width (screen :grid-width)
       grid-height (screen :grid-height)]
    (loop [x 0
           y 0
           term term]
      (if (= x grid-width)
        (if (= y grid-height)
          term
          (recur 0 (inc y) ((term :set-char!) term x y tex-x tex-y color)))
        (recur (inc x) y ((term :set-char!) term x y tex-x tex-y color))))))
```

The "terminal" in the doc comment is referring to a library I am working on that is supposed to simulate a terminal, that may be used for application development.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `set` function? It shadows [`clojure.core/set`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/set) and appears to just be a less useful version of [`assoc`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc).

Comment: The code I have is a whole lot more advanced, and in it the name of the set function is not actually set. Rather, I have one set function (if you will) setting one tile in a grid of tiles (with help from an x, y, tex-x, tex-y and color parameter), returning the current state of the application. And so, what I am trying to do is loop over the entire grid of x and y coordinates settings all tiles to the same type of tile: thus the necessity of a set method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to advice to use `reduce` (which are totally correct ones), i would also propose to you a variant for your update (setting grid values)

let's say you have this term definition:

```
(def term {:screen {:grid-width 5
                    :grid-height 3}
           :set-char! (fn [term & other]
                        (println :setting other)
                        term)})
```

first of all you could replace `loop/recur` with a combination of `reduce` (for term updating) and `for` list comprehensions (`(for [x (range 2) y (range-3)] [x y])` generates all the the coordinate pairs)

```
(defn fill!
  [{{:keys [grid-width grid-height]} :screen
    set-char! :set-char!}
   tex-x tex-y color]
  (reduce (fn [term [x y]] (set-char! term x y tex-x tex-y color))
          term
          (for [x (range grid-width)
                y (range grid-height)]
            [x y])))
```

in repl:

```
user> (fill! term 101 102 103)
:setting (0 0 101 102 103)
:setting (0 1 101 102 103)
:setting (0 2 101 102 103)
:setting (1 0 101 102 103)
:setting (1 1 101 102 103)
:setting (1 2 101 102 103)
:setting (2 0 101 102 103)
:setting (2 1 101 102 103)
:setting (2 2 101 102 103)
:setting (3 0 101 102 103)
:setting (3 1 101 102 103)
:setting (3 2 101 102 103)
:setting (4 0 101 102 103)
:setting (4 1 101 102 103)
:setting (4 2 101 102 103)

{:screen {:grid-width 5, :grid-height 3}, :set-char! #function[user/fn--19918]}
```

ok. it works, but as long as your set-char! function is only being used for side effects (in my case to print string, in yours to update screen), you can go without the reduction, using on of clojure's functions designed for this exact case (`do[run|seq|all]`), namely `doseq`:

```
(defn fill2!
  [{{:keys [grid-width grid-height]} :screen set-char! :set-char!}
   tex-x tex-y color]
  (doseq [x (range grid-width) y (range grid-height)]
    (set-char! term x y tex-x tex-y color))
  term)
```

which would do exactly the same as the first variant.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce)

```
(let [foo [3 4 2 5 8]]
  (reduce (fn [acc k]
            (set acc k 32))
          foo
          (range (count foo))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a sequence of 5 instances of the value `32`, use [`repeat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeat):

```
(repeat 5 32)
;=> (32 32 32 32 32)
```

If you need the result to be a vector, use [`vec`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vec):

```
(vec (repeat 5 32))
;=> [32 32 32 32 32]
```

If you need the result to be the same size as an existing collection, use [`count`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/count):

```
(vec (repeat (count [3 4 2 5 8]) 32))
;=> [32 32 32 32 32]
```

You could package this up into a function if you want:

```
(defn fill [v x]
  (vec (repeat (count v) x)))

(fill [3 4 2 5 8] 32)
;=> [32 32 32 32 32]
```

Answer (score 0):

Redefining Clojure's core `set` is probably not such a good idea.  It also doesn't seem necessary here, so I just used `assoc` directly in the examples below.

You can use `constantly` to run your function the desired number of times.  It returns a list, so the extra call to `vec` is just to get your desired data type:

```
user.core=> (let [foo [3 4 2 5 8]]
         #_=>   (vec (map (constantly 32) foo)))
[32 32 32 32 32]
```

And here is a variation on @SerCe's answer that uses a reader macro, which I find a bit cleaner.

```
user.core=> (let [foo [3 4 2 5 8]]
         #_=>   (reduce #(assoc %1 %2 32) foo (range (count foo))))
[32 32 32 32 32]
```